# Error 25 while using Amazon's Feed API for inventory fulfillment

Tags: xml, amazon-web-services, amazon-mws

I have been stuck with this one for a little while and could do with some advice. Upon submitting a _POST_ORDER_FULFILLMENT_DATA_ feed, I am given an error code 25 : "We are unable to process the XML feed because one or more items are invalid. Please re-submit the feed".

Everything appears to be valid according to the XML schema, and have triple checked the order and orderItem Id's and they are all correct. I have tried various adjustments of the date / time of the  field to no avail.  I have also tried using CarrierName instead of CarrierCode, but that also made no difference.

The XML we are submitting is as follows:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<AmazonEnvelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="amzn-envelope.xsd">
<Header>
<DocumentVersion>1.01</DocumentVersion>
<MerchantIdentifier>X_XXXXXXXXX_XXXXXXXX</MerchantIdentifier>
</Header>

<MessageType>OrderFulfillment</MessageType>
<Message>
<MessageID>1</MessageID>
<OrderFulfillment>
<AmazonOrderID>026-5484990-9733146</AmazonOrderID>
<FulfillmentDate>2014-08-16T15:09:11+00:00</FulfillmentDate>
<FulfillmentData>
<CarrierCode>Royal Mail</CarrierCode>
<ShippingMethod>Standard</ShippingMethod>
</FulfillmentData>
<item>
<AmazonOrderItemCode>69618547819979</AmazonOrderItemCode>
<Quantity>2</Quantity>
</item>
</OrderFulfillment>
</Message>
</AmazonEnvelope>
```

Does anybody have any advice or suggestions, I am obviously missing something but do not know what.  I am using PHP and the provided library to submit feeds, which is working beautifully for everything else.  This result is the same whether using my PHP code or submitting via Amazon's scratchpad so it is obviously something to do with either the feed format or the items being ordered themselves, just don't know what

Many thanks in advanced for any help and advice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, the XSDs provided by Amazon are incomplete (if anybody has a full source, I'd love to hear where to find them). The issue with your feed however is an easy one: Your `<item>` tag should read `<Item>`, with a capital I and corresponding closing `</Item>` tag.

Comment: from where one can get AmazonOrderItemCode ?

Comment: @Moax6629 That is part of the order report you probably processed before sending fulfillment data.